# How to ensure a regex matches only after a certain character

Tags: c++, regex

Is there a way to specify regex that would match a string but from a certain position in this string? What I mean is that I have line:

```
"Somebodys_value is % value"
```

and I'd like to check if my regex matches this sentence but only after % sign.

Comment: I don't understand your question, if your regex is just `%` then it will match your input. A regex does NOT need to match all of its input. What do you want to achieve exactly? Find the index of that %?

Comment: @fge I want to find if anything after % matches my regex which by the way isn't %

Comment: Is the position of the string known beforehand or is it dependent on a specific character/string?

Comment: Well, just try and find the first %, if there isn't any you don't have a match, and in the other case try and match the regex on the substring starting from the % until the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only RegEx you just include the % in your pattern.  If your pattern is `value`, you can change it to `%.*value`.

---

Another way, that's more dependent on your engine, is to provide an offset.  You can use a `strpos` like function to find the %, and say to start matching after that.

---

Yet another method is to copy everything after the % into a new buffer/string, and then try to match that.

---

Any more specifics depend on the engine you're using.

*edit:*
It sounds like you don't want the % in your matches.  A few implementation specific ways to do this are...

- `(?:%).*value` where the % is in a non-capturing group
- `%\K.*value` where \K discards everything before it (limited support)
- `%(.*value)` where you will just use the first subpattern (often called $1).
- or you can just do any operations starting at sub 1, and ignore the % at sub 0.

Answer (score 1):

Superficially, it seems like you could use this regex (where the slashes are simple delimiters):

```
/%.*value/
```

It looks for your value after it's seen the percentage.  Coding that up in C++ is only marginally fiddlier, but since you've given no indication of which regex package you're using, it is hard to know what code to write.  There are a lot of possible regex packages you could be planning to use.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the particular regex API you're using, of course, but I see two different options:

1. Advance your `char*` to point to the `%` before calling your `match()` function
2. Include the '%' in the regex itself, as @JonathanLeffler says.

Version 1 might be more efficient, but only if you already know where the '%' is!